# Row validation of excel cells in Java POI

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I am trying to implement a data driven aspect to my test automation framework.  I have created a fe functions that seem to work alright that retrieve col/row number of parameter, get the data from a specific cell, update specific cells and so forth.

I am now testing this with a script that basically has 2 columns.  The first column is the username and the second column is the password.  I can iterate over these rows, columns with no problem.

I had an issue where if there was a blank cell it would crash,  but I resolved that with some error handling and if there is a black cell it returns the string "Empty cell".

I am having a minor issue whereby if some of the test data is out of alignment:

[image: The rows are out of alignment]

I am not sure how to handle such an issue.  I have added some validation if both cells are empty(it skips the row).  How do I get it to skip these types of rows altogether and just take data which has 2 cell entries?

My code as it stands is as follows:

```
int endMarker = edc.getExcelParameterRow(edc, 0, nextColumnMarker);

    System.out.println(endMarker);

    int columnParam = edc.getExcelParameterCol(edc, 0, ExcelDataUserName);
    System.out.println(columnParam);

    open_chrome_browser();
    Logout lo = new Logout();



    //get all of the usernames
    for (i = 0; i <endMarker-1;i++){
        String param1_celldata = edc.getExcelData(0, i+1, columnParam);
        String param2_celldata = edc.getExcelData(0, i+1, columnParam+1);

        //iterate over the username passwords of the data.xls sheet to login and out as different users

        if(param1_celldata.contains("Empty cell")&&param2_celldata.contains("Empty cell")){
            i++;
        }


        LoginPage.login(driver, edc.getExcelData(0, i+1, columnParam), edc.getExcelData(0, i+1, columnParam+1));
        lo.logout_user_out(driver);
```

I cant do the following:

```
if(param1_celldata.contains("Empty cell")&&param2_celldata.contains("Empty cell")){
            i++;
        }
        if(param1_celldata.contains("Empty cell")){
            i++;
        }
        if(param2_celldata.contains("Empty cell")){
            i++;
        }
```

The following doesn't fit the bill either:

```
if(param1_celldata.contains("Empty cell")&&param2_celldata.contains("Empty cell")){
            i++;
        }
        if(param1_celldata.contains("Empty cell")||param2_celldata.contains("Empty cell")){
            i++;
        }
```

I just want the tool to skip these weird mis aligned cells altogether.  How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the logic a bit and try the below? This will skip rows where either cell is empty.

```
for (i = 0; i < endMarker - 1; i++)
{
    String param1_celldata = edc.getExcelData(0, i + 1, columnParam);
    String param2_celldata = edc.getExcelData(0, i + 1, columnParam + 1);

    // iterate over the username passwords of the data.xls sheet to login and out as different users
    if (!param1_celldata.contains("Empty cell") && !param2_celldata.contains("Empty cell"))
    {
        LoginPage.login(driver, param1_celldata, param2_celldata);
        lo.logout_user_out(driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: The change reads... if Cell1 is not empty and Cell2 is not empty then log in and log out. If either cell *is* empty, then the log in and log out step is skipped taking you back to the start of the `for` and incrementing `i`.

Comment: Thanks Gowrishankar I didnt realise I could add an exclamation mark to negate the clause: !param1_celldata.contains("Empty cell").  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction is working now.